# Unable to pull few public docker image

Tags: docker, docker-selenium

Using win 10 Enterprise
Installed docker for windows latest version.
WSL integration available
Ubuntu-18.04
Logged in to docker in power shell
`docker pull selenium/node-chrome`  fails with error
`filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256:`

Tried various solutions in google like restarting, reinstalling etc. nothing works
How to debug whats going wrong?

Strangely this works in my personal laptop. Not working in office laptop

Does proxy / VPN causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was issue with proxy. After changing proxy settings in docker and laptop settings it worked

Comment: How did you change proxy settings in order to get it working? Thx

Comment: In docker app,goto settings,what's ur proxy server id,update it